# Recursive Loop Issue

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to search for my `name` in a text using Recursive Loop.

But it's returning half of the letters and sometimes `undefined`.

```js
var text = 'huurrr hurrrh u rajat huhuhw dwhidwid sdijhsid \
    hurhrhr hrher rajat ekkdwihd ruidhwui rajat';

var myName = 'rajat';
var hits = [];

for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  if (text[i] === 'r') {
    for (var j = i; j <= myName.length; j++) {
      hits.push(myName[j]);
    }
  }
}
console.log(hits);
```

Can somebody help with this please ?

Comment: `j <= i + myName.length` and `hits.push(text[j]);` . Overall the logic is wrong

Comment: Whats a `Recursive Loop` ?

Comment: Why are you looping? There is functions available to check if the 'your name' is in the string, for example, the match() funtion

Comment: @FlyingGambit He means `nested loops`

Comment: @Rajat Just because `if (text[i] === 'r') {` first letter is `r` does not mean that the remaining characters will be `ajat`

Comment: Walk through your code in the debugger and watch what it is doing at each line. Or execute the code in your head and see what it is doing. By the way, what is your desired output? Can the string occur more than one time?

Comment: @FlyingGambit Yes thats true. But I believe OP is just starting with coding and is playing with some stuff to learn. Lets take it ease on him and help in not only to solve but to learn as well

Comment: thanks for the suggestions everyone. i am a learner to coding. i know there are several alternates to a question. But i was trying to solve it this way.

Comment: @FlyingGambit can u please provide an explanation of the logic u suggested in ur 1st comment. why you included i in the j<= i+ myName.length

Comment: @RajatChauhan I realised that `j<= i+myName.length` would just lengthen the solution and might confuse the OP so initialized j with 0  in my answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
var text = 'huurrr hurrrh u rajat huhuhw dwhidwid sdijhsid \
    hurhrhr hrher rajat ekkdwihd ruidhwui rajat';

var myName = 'rajat';
var hits = [];

for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  if (text[i] === myName[0] && text[i + 1] == myName[1]) {
    for (var j = 0; j <= myName.length; j++) {
      if(myName[j] == text[i + j])
        hits.push(myName[j]);
    }
  }
}
console.log(hits);
```

Or you could use a regular expression and the String.prototype.match:

```js
var text = 'huurrr hurrrh u rajat huhuhw dwhidwid sdijhsid \
    hurhrhr hrher rajat ekkdwihd ruidhwui rajat';
var myName = "rajat";
var regex= new RegExp(myName,"g");
var hits = text.match(regex);

console.log(hits)
```

Comment: Your first example won't work at all. It will push a bunch of letters which happen to match.

Answer (score 0):

> This can be achieved without Recursive Loop as follows

```js
var text = 'huurrr hurrrh u rajat huhuhw dwhidwid sdijhsid \ hurhrhr hrher rajat ekkdwihd ruidhwui rajat';


var regex = /rajat/gi, result, indices = [];
while ( (result = regex.exec(text)) ) {
    indices.push(result.index);
}
console.log(indices);// Array containing  index number where your string exists
console.log(indices.length); // Nmber of time occurence of string
```

Comment: Please explain your attempt. Just putting working code is not enough. **What and Why** have you changed?

Comment: I have feeling that the OP is using two for loops intentionally, maybe as a homework for practicing

Answer (score 0):

**Walking through your code**

```js
var text = 'huurrr hurrrh u rajat huhuhw dwhidwid sdijhsid \
    hurhrhr hrher rajat ekkdwihd ruidhwui rajat';

var myName = 'rajat';
var hits = [];

for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  // You are assuming that if the word starts with "r" then the rest of the characters would "ajat", which is wrong.
  // Lets scan from the left of the text, it will go inside the if-condition as soon as it sees the `r` in the first `huurrr`.
  // Therefore when i = 3 (remember text[0] = h, text[1] = u, text[2] = u, text[3] = r), code will go inside the if-condition
  if (text[i] === 'r') { 
   // Here you are assigning  `j=i` which means `j=3` and `myName.length = 5`, so it simplifies to
   // for (var j = 3; j <= 5; j++) {
   
    for (var j = i; j <= myName.length; j++) {
     // When `j=3`, you trying to push a character from `myName` and not from `text`. 
     // myName[3] = a , myName[4] = t , myName[5] = undefined (because index starts from 0 and there is nothing at index 5)  
       hits.push(myName[j]);
    }
    // When above for loop finishes `hit` will have ["a", "t", undefined]
  }
  // Code will continue and execute for i = 4 and so on till it finishes
}
console.log(hits);
```

**How to fix it**

```js
var text = 'huurrr hurrrh u rajat huhuhw dwhidwid sdijhsid \
    hurhrhr hrher rajat ekkdwihd ruidhwui rajat';

var myName = 'rajat';
var hits = [];

for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
 // We will use this if-condition as an entry condition
 if (text[i] === 'r') { 
  // No matter what the value of `i` is, we want to run the loop 5 times (5 is the length of myName) 
  // Lets initialize `j = 0` (because index of string starts from 0)
  // Also `j <= myName.length` should be `j < myName.length`, otherwise the loop would run 6 times
  for (var j = 0; j < myName.length; j++) {
   // We need additional checking to make sure we are looking for the string `rajat`
   // if `i=3`, (remember the word is "huurrr")
   // `text[3+0] = 'r'`, `text[3+1] = 'r'`, `text[3+2] = 'r'`, `text[3+3] = ' '`, `text[3+4] = 'h'`
   // That means code won't     
   if(text[i+j] === myName[j]){
    // For `j = 0`, hit will have the 1st character  (See below how to fix this flaw)
    hits.push(myName[j]);
   }else{ 
    // add an else condition so that this for loop execution stops even if a character does not match. 
    // That means, for `j=1`, it will break;
    break;
   }
  }
 }
}
console.log(hits);
```

**Fixing the flaw**

```js
var text = 'huurrr hurrrh u rajat huhuhw dwhidwid sdijhsid \
    hurhrhr hrher rajat ekkdwihd ruidhwui rajat';

var myName = 'rajat';
var hits = [];

for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
 if (text[i] === 'r') { 
  // To fix the flaw, I am going to use a boolean flag
  // The flag will have two states, true and false. 
  // I am going to keeep the default value of the flag as `true`
  var flag = true;

  // I am going to create a temp array to hold our values.
  // If the flag is true then only we will use it, 
  // because it means that tmp holds the characters ['r','a','j','a','t'].
  var tmp = [];

  for (var j = 0; j < myName.length; j++) {
   if(text[i+j] === myName[j]){
    tmp.push(myName[j]);
   }else{ 
    // If we come here, then it means there is a non matching character
    // so set flag as `false`
    flag = false;
    break;
   }
  }

  // check if flag is true, if yes then push values of tmp to hits
  if(flag === true){
   hits.push(...tmp); // The three dots is a way of spreading the elements, its called spread operator
  }
 }
}
console.log(hits);
```

Read about [The spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), below is a pic demonstrating what would have happened if I simply used `hits.push(tmp);`

[image]

**Note:** Your problem has many solutions, this is just one way of solving it